# jquery cycle, link to other page on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, cycle, preventdefault

I'm working on a website using jquery cycle (1st version).
I have pages including a slideshow, I navigate into my slideshow with #next function.
when clicking on my last slide of my slideshow it redirect me to another page (var random_next_url_enfant).

it works fine, but my cycle starts again just before changing to the next page. (last slide, then first slide displays briefly and then link to the next page)...
see this example :

http://www.jacques-ferrier.com/projets/choisy-le-roi/

I would like to know if someone knows a trick to stop the slideshow and change page without latency. When the last slide from my slideshow is displayed, stop the sliding navigation, and when clicking goes directly to my link. I thought that the "e.preventDefault()" would do this but it doesn't.

here is my js code :

```
$('#slider_projets').cycle({
            speed:    600, //temps d'animation
            timeout:  0, //fréquence
            fx: 'scrollLeft',
            //compteur//
            pager: "#nav",
            after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
                $('#counter').text((options.currSlide + 1) + ' / ' + (options.slideCount));
                slideIndex = options.currSlide;
                nextIndex = slideIndex + 1;
                prevIndex = slideIndex - 1;
                if (slideIndex == options.slideCount - 1) {
                    nextIndex = 0;
                    var random_next_url_enfant = $("#random_next_url_enfant").val();
                    $('#next').on("click", function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        window.location = random_next_url_enfant;
                    });
                }

                if (slideIndex === 0) {
                    prevIndex = options.slideCount - 1;
                }

            }

        });

    $('#next').click(function() {
        $('#slider_projets').cycle(nextIndex, "scrollLeft");
    });
```

here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GahHQ/

hope you can help me,

thanks a lot

Comment: What would happen if you removed the line: nextIndex = 0 in the if statement?

Comment: hello @nocturns2 thanks a lot ! it works fine, great ! but on the other hand my navigation using space bar key and right arrow key doesn't work anymore at the end of the slideshow, I mean they control the slideshow, but at the end of the slideshow the slide starts again... do you know why ? http://jsfiddle.net/GahHQ/2/